# ProgressDialog not showing (behind TabActivity or Activity)

Tags: android, progressdialog, resume, tabactivity

In my app I've got a ProgressDialog. It is shown by the user pressing a button in a Activity that is part of a TabActivity. The ProgressDialog works perfectly until the app is minimized and then resumed. It then seems like the ProgressDialog is stuck behind the TabActivity or Activity. It responds true to "isShowing", and can briefly be visible until the TabActivity and Activity are resumed.

Is there some way to bring it to the front, or create it in a different way that ensures it is the item "on top"? The context for the ProgressDialog has been set to both the TabActivity and the Activity without any success.